# Sharing Wifi through Ethernet in Linux

Tags: networking

I am trying to share my host PCs internet(Connected to Wifi) to the target device through an ethernet cable connected between them. I am able to ping the target from the host and vice versa. but am unable to connect to the internet from the target.
**Command outputs of Target**

```
# route
kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway      Genmask        Flags    Metric    Ref   Use   Iface
default        192.168.2.1  0.0.0.0        UG       0         0     0     eth0
192.168.2.0    *            255.255.255.0  U        0         0     0     eth0
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:03:de:92:f1:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interface file auto-generated by buildroot

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.2.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

**Command outputs of Host**

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
default         atf-Latitude-E6 0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 eno1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.186.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
192.168.234.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:26:0a:85:68:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
    inet 192.168.2.1/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5e26:aff:fe85:68ed/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:11:96:f0:6a:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.246/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 2303sec preferred_lft 2303sec
    inet6 2409:408c:8d09:225a:47b5:ad9a:e876:20a8/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3506sec preferred_lft 3506sec
    inet6 2409:408c:8d09:225a:89b5:1ef1:95fc:ffbb/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3506sec preferred_lft 3506sec
    inet6 fe80::16e0:e90c:3910:62ca/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.186.1/24 brd 192.168.186.255 scope global vmnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.234.1/24 brd 192.168.234.255 scope global vmnet8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:1d:6c:ab:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: 
        - 192.168.2.1/24
      routes: 
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

`ping 8.8.8.8` in the Target hangs.
Also how do I add a nameserver to the target?

Comment: Enable IP forwarding on the host machine: `# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup, as described, is missing 2 crucial functions, IP forwarding and network address translation.

You've set up your addresses and routes correctly, but when a packet arrives at "host" from "target" that are destined for some other machine the default behavior is to simply discard the packet, you need to enable forwarding (as pointed out by Riley) with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

The next issue is that when that packet arrives at the router on your LAN, the router isn't going to know what to do with a packet with source address `192.168.2.2`. The packet may be dropped at this stage, or when a response comes back, but it's not going to make it back to your "target" machine. You can solve this issue by telling the "host" machine to re-write the source address of outgoing packets so the routers down the line know where to send responses. You can do this easily in linux with `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i eno1 -o wlp2s0 -j MASQUERADE`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me to improve my understanding about routing too